# Setting authenticated user while testing Meteor app

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor

I have added user roles to my Meteor app and need to test permissions over certain server methods. These methods are written such as, for example :

```
Meteor.methods({
  'inventory.update.qty'(id, qty) {
    // SECURITY
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['manage-stock'],  'inventory-items')) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('inv.crud', 'Access denied');
    }

    const modifier = {
      $inc: { qty }
    };

    InventoryItems.update(id, modifier);
  },
});
```

But how can I set this `this.userId` while running tests?

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` can be called from methods running on server.

Comment: You are not reading the question... and methods should use `this.userId`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [`this.setUserId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-setUserId) (which is a a function bound to a method invocation object....the `this` object).

Depending on how you are running your tests, you could define a "logMeInAs" meteor method that you call client side to login as a specific user before running a test.

```
Meteor.methods({
  signMeIn:function(userId) {
    this.setUserId(userId);
  }
});
```

Then on the client call this before running your test.

```
Meteor.call(<id of user you are testing with>);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. See : https://forums.meteor.com/t/rest-api-how-do-i-ddp-connect-as-a-specific-user-on-the-server/15783/2

Comment: I think this didn't work in this case because they were trying to use `this.setUserId()` in a method they called from the server (using a server side route).  "Error: Can't call setUserId on a server initiated method call".  It should work fine if the Meteor method was called from the client.

Comment: With that said...let me test this out for future knowledge's sake.